# How to override dnsconfig in kubernetes deployment kind

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, alpine-linux, coredns

I'm trying to override dnsconfig (searchdomain particularly) of my alpine based pod.

But it seems [dnsconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config) is available in pod object.

Is there anyway to provide dnsconfig in deployment object or any other workaround to override searchdomain of that particular pod.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the [`dnsConfig`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config) inside `spec.template` object.

This is basically a template for your `Deployment` which will be used to create pods.

Deployment might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.17
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      dnsPolicy: "None"
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - 1.2.3.4
        searches:
          - test.test.com
          - test.test.org
```